# automatic export to excel using datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable

The export to excel can be added by

```
$('table.data-table').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: 'no-sort',
    orderable: false
  }],
```

But I want to download an excel file automatically when I initiate the `datatable`

Is there an option to do that?
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr77dgmt/3/) with export to excel working on click of excel button

I want it to happen automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `click()` the excel button in the `initComplete` callback :

```
initComplete: function() {
   $('.buttons-excel').click()
}
```

forked fiddle (not intentionally) -> **https://jsfiddle.net/850z70do/**

Comment: ahhh how did not think of this !!
Thanks for the help David

Comment: @vignesh and u can just append to css .buttons-excel{display:none;} to hide that button

Comment: @MichałSzałapski I'm not gonna show the table, I will be hiding the container div of the table itself, so probably that should hide everything. I just need the export to excel functionality from datatable :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a 'drawCallback' option to your datatables configuration.

```
    drawCallback: function () {
      $('.buttons-excel').trigger('click')
    }
```